# How to get blur effect similar to Apple maps status bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uiblureffect, gaussianblur

I'm working on a map based iOS 11 application and want to make the status bar blurred exactly like it appears in the Apple maps.

This is how it looks on the Maps app:
[image]

Currently, I'm using UIVisualEffectView to replicate this effect. Here's my code:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
blurredStatusBar = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurredStatusBar?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(blurredStatusBar!)
```

However, whatever UIBlurEffect I use, I'm not able to replicate the effect like Maps app. Here's how it looks for different effects:

**.regular**
[image]

**.prominent**
[image]

**.light**
[image]

**.extraLight**
[image]

**I just want to the blur the status bar, without adding any saturation, vibrancy or any white color tint.**

There is an instance property - [backgroundFilters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410827-backgroundfilters), which, possibly could have helped me  but unfortunately it is not available for layers on iOS.

One possible solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254444/calayers-backgroundfilters-doesn-nothing-on-uiview) was to capture the UIView content inside an image, then blurring and showing it. However, this is not a feasible solution in my case because I've got a map underneath the status bar which can be panned. It does not makes sense to continuously capture the underneath map as an image and blur it while the map is being panned.

I tried using [ILTranslucentView](https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView), which is a little subclass of UIView that provide native iOS 7+ blur (translucent) effect.
This is how it appeared:

[image]

I tried a couple of different approaches like [this](https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Blurable), but to no use.

Comment: Hi, i think Apple did not use UIBlurEffect, in order to achieve this effect try to add [this lib](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/DynamicBlurView) like a status bar view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for the above problem. I used [VisualEffectView](https://github.com/efremidze/VisualEffectView) to achieve the effect. It lets you to customise the properties like colortint, blurRadius, scale of blur of your VisualEffectView. However, this should be used with caution. It utilizes a private UIKit API to do its magic; submitting this code to the App Store adds the risk of being rejected!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `UIToolbar`.
It has the same blur effect as `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar` that cannot be achieved with `UIBlurEffect`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try Following.

```
yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)   // Or   UIBlurEffectStyle.dark    
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = viewAdvancefilter.blurredView.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
yourView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: I already have stated that using UIBlurEffect and UIVisualEffectView did not help.  I also have posted the screenshot showing how these effects differ from the blur effect in the apple maps app. I suggest you to read the question again.