# How to create status bar background in the Navigation Bar without Navigation Bar Titles, items, and more?

Tags: ios, swift, background, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

Take me 7 hours to researching around the coding and nothing to answer it. I believed Apple created its own Apple Map with only a status bar area in the navigation bar. I have tried to look for this trick code to enable it like that green background of safe area guidelines.

[image]

Let me know if you know the code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you can use a simply trick: add a containerView and do your stuff in it and assign the color that you want to dummy status bar simply changing the background color of the view:
declare containerView and the label in it:

```
let containerView = UIView()
let labelInfo = UILabel()
```

now in viewDidLoad set objects and constraints:

```
view.backgroundColor = .green // change color for status bar color
    
labelInfo.text = "do your stuff here"
labelInfo.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .semibold)
labelInfo.textColor = .black
labelInfo.textAlignment = .center
labelInfo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
containerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
view.addSubview(containerView)
containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
containerView.addSubview(labelInfo)
labelInfo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
labelInfo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
labelInfo.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
labelInfo.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

this is the results:
[image]

Comment: Nice one! I could try that method. One thing that I have felt about Apple Map and Snapchat with the new update has show blur background with the status bars look like Apple's Navigation bar codes. I know Navigation Bar always uses it to show the top layer, and anything is under the layer like that.

Comment: @AntonioAdrianChavez Hi, I haven't seen this update yet, do you have a link or a screenshot where I can see it? Thx :)

Comment: I am not talking about blur effect, but Navigation Bar like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52112621/how-to-get-blur-effect-similar-to-apple-maps-status-bar

Comment: @AntonioAdrianChavez but that in your example link is a status bar not navigation bar...